# Create Stack/Deck of CardsView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've been checking CardView's docs to create a stack of cards and found multiple libraries that uses swiping features.

What I am looking for is a way to implement like this one ( by @Vikram) but it doesn't support ICS.

I wanna create a Cards Stack, to ask the user some questions, sort of a survey and for each card: a question will appear and the next card will be shown after the user answers with Yes or No (buttons).

So Can you guys help me with this one ? Can I use recycle view to create one ?

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: maybe here you will find something usefull https://android-arsenal.com/tag/15

Comment: Thank you for your reply @j2ko, I've checked all the libraries there but Unfortunatly, didn't find what I am looking for. Most of them have the swipe effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [library](https://github.com/aaronbond/SwipeDeck2) that can achieve this, with the swiping set to `disabled`